# Trying to sent JSON to Alamofire but it's always _TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray

Tags: arrays, json, swift

I am trying to make an Alamofire `.POST` with a `[String:AnyObject]` , the AnyObject is `[String]` (want to make it `[[String:AnyOject]]`, but does not work with any array. I am trying to create a JSON and sent it but the output of my json is `_TtCs21_SwiftDeferredNSArray`. So the server is not responding properly. I know that it works ok with `String:Any` in Swift 3 but I have Swift 2.3 and Alamofire uses only String:AnyObject

My code:

```
var data = [String]()
for product inproducts {
     data.append(product.id)
}
let params : [String:AnyObject] = ["products":data]
```

I tried many different combinations Array , but its always the same problem.

Comment: Alamofire expects '[String:AnyObject]' , I want to sent an array of JSON , so I have to use '[String:[[String:AnyObject]]'